# Customize header of DXGrid (DevExpress wpf grid control)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I am working on wpf project in which i am following MVVM pattern and using Devexpress Wpf Tools.
I have to implement a gridControl which will show monthly data.Here in the image you can see 2 weeks data. I have to boxed all days data with their respective week. I don't know how to implement this  layered header gridcontrol.

No of Week display could be dynamic.

[image]

How can i implement this UI ?Any idea?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to implement banded view. 
Thus, I suggest you review the following KB article:
[Advanced Banded View Layout with attached behavior](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18529.aspx).

Comment: thanx DmitryG that  is exactly i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's better to address question to DX support - they can provide any sample you need. With no sample or DX version used, it's hard to say what template you should change.

Look into GridHeaderTemplate into sources.